# redirect includes port number - spring web mvc

Tags: spring, tomcat, redirect

I have a Spring webapp with some `RedirectView` redirects configured. With the code using the `RedirectView` instead of a straight `ModelAndView` and returning a jsp, the redirect does its thing but it appends the port number to the response. Is there a way I can prevent this?

```
mView.addObject(Constants.RESPONSE_MESSAGE, this.appConfig.getMessagePasswordExpired());
mView.setViewName(this.appConfig.getExpiredRedirect());
```

`this.appConfig.getExpiredRedirect()` would return `redirect:/ui/user-account/password`

Redirect includes port number but shouldn't.